# Something wrong with loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

It is a batch file (in windows 7).
I tried some combinations and changes, but the exact output was not achieved. Please check below.

```
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

   set c=

   for %i in (1 2 3 4) do (
     set b=%c% %i,2013/
     call echo %b%
     set c=%b%
   )
```

I want output like below:

```
1,2013/

1,2013/2,2013/

1,2013/2,2013/3,2013/

1,2013/2,2013/3,2013/4,2013/
```

But it is coming like below.

C:\Users\Ashutosh PC>setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

C:\Users\Ashutosh PC>set c=

C:\Users\Ashutosh PC>for %i in (1 2 3 4) do (
More? set b=%c% %i,2013/
More? call echo %b%
More? set c= %b%
More?
More? )

C:\Users\Ashutosh PC>(
set b=%c% 1,2013/
 call echo %b%
 set c= %b%
)
%c% 1,2013/

C:\Users\Ashutosh PC>(
set b=%c% 2,2013/
 call echo %b%
 set c= %b%
)
%c% 2,2013/

C:\Users\Ashutosh PC>(
set b=%c% 3,2013/
 call echo %b%
 set c= %b%
)
%c% 3,2013/

C:\Users\Ashutosh PC>(
set b=%c% 4,2013/
 call echo %b%
 set c= %b%
)
%c% 4,2013/

C:\Users\Ashutosh PC>

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: And what output are you actually getting?

Comment: it is batch file in windows @RobinGreen

Answer (score 2):

```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

   set "c="

   for %%i in (1 2 3 4) do (
     set b=!c! %%i,2013/
     call echo !b!
     set c=!b!
   )
   endlocal
```

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php

Comment: thanks npocmaka for your reply but i am getting error in executing code given by you.    

C:\Users\Ashutosh PC>for %%i in (1 2 3 4) do (
%%i was unexpected at this time.

it seems cmd prompt do not recognize double (%%) sign.

Comment: Your question said "It is a batch file".  npocmaka's answer works in a batch file.  If you want to execute from a CMD prompt you need to use %i instead of %%i.

Comment: hey RGuggisberg and npocmaka .. thanks much for your support...just now tested through batch file(rather CMD)...it worked great.